# ExtJS Column Chart with 2 Y axes and title

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

I'm trying to plot a column chart with two series and two Y axis
,but  it show four title on right side. I expect to show two title data and data2.

Please help me to fix this problem

Something like that :
http://jsfiddle.net/7sstvj84

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        fields: ['name', 'data','data2'],
        data: [{
            'name': 'metric one',
            'data': 20,
           'data2': 2
        }, {
            'name': 'metric two',
            'data': 7,
          'data2': 20
        }, {
            'name': 'metric three',
            'data': 5,
          'data2': 17
        }]
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 500,
      height:300,
        animate: true,
        store: store,
       legend: {
                position: 'right'
            },
        axes: [{
            type: 'Numeric',
            position: 'left',
            fields: ['data'],
           title: true,
            title: 'Sample Values',
            grid: true,
            minimum: 0
        }, {
            type: 'Numeric',
            position: 'right',
            fields: ['data2'],
          title: true,
            title: 'Values',
            grid: false,
            minimum: 0
        },{
            type: 'Category',
            position: 'bottom',
            fields: ['name'],
            title: 'Sample Metrics'
        }],
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            axis: 'left',
            highlight: true,
            xField: 'name',
            yField: ['data','name']
        },{
            type: 'column',
            axis: 'right',
            highlight: true,
            xField: 'name',
            yField: ['name','data2']
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like is missing the required files!

```
   Ext.require([
      'Ext.data.JsonStore',
'Ext.chart.Chart',
'Ext.chart.series.Column',
'Ext.chart.axis.Numeric',
'Ext.chart.axis.Category'
    ]);
```

I tried your code and only include the above snippet to make it work.
If you are going to use the code in a web application you might consider creating a class and setting up your namespace.